# Slickgrid DblClick & Click

Tags: click, slickgrid, double-click

I am working with SlickGrid and would like to use both the `Click` and `DblClick` events.

If I do a double click, first the click event will be shown, but then the `DblClick` won't fire. Here is what I have:

```
TreePopupGrid.onClick.subscribe(function (e, args){
    var cell = TreePopupGrid.getCellFromEvent(e)
    var row = cell.row;
    var item = TreePopupDataView.getItem(row);
    alert("single"+item.id);
});
TreePopupGrid.onDblClick.subscribe(function (e, args){
    var cell = TreePopupGrid.getCellFromEvent(e)
    var row = cell.row;
    var item = TreePopupDataView.getItem(row);
    alert("double"+item.id);
});
```

How can I use both events?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the grid option: enableCellNavigation: true. I think this fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but actually, the option that allows this is autoEdit: true.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue. My fix was to debounce the click event:

```
 grid.onDblClick.subscribe(this.doubleClickHandler);
 grid.onClick.subscribe(_.debounce(this.clickHandler, 500));
```

Notice that I've been using the lodash debounce implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you could use both but the way you have it now they will both fire at the same time during a double click because that is two single clicks. You wont get the desired results. You should wrap them in the jQuery $.dblclick() and $.click() handlers. That should get you what you want.